# About using http in Heroku server?

Tags: heroku

I am a newbie to Heroku server. I found the default connection method is https.

If I switched to http, I will received the following errors when accessing
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin *** is therefore not allowed access.

Any idea to enable http access?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not a protocol issue. Have you checked domain?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to the same-origin policy. Seems that some of your requests are mixed between plain http and https which all modern browsers interpret as having different origins.

Without seeing additional debug information, I'm going to guess the main page is still loaded via https, but the page assets (images, javascript, css etc.) are now loaded via http.

Assuming this is correct, the first step is to ensure the main html page is loaded using the same origin (same domain, same scheme (http or https) etc.).